# NSXMLParser problem

Tags: iphone, nsxmlparser

I have an xml file with some rows like this:

```
  <Country ID="" Name="Italy" />
  <City ID="" Name="Rome" />
  <Place ID="" Name="Colosseum">
```

but when I parse it the element Country or City or Place are empty (line break)

My code is:

    `- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string{
        if ([currentElement isEqual:@"Country"]) {
             NSLog(@"Country %@", string);
        }
    }`

Any help is appreciated.

Thanks,
Max

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The values you see in your xml are the element attributes, not element data. So it wont show up in 'foundCharacters' method.
You will have to fetch the attribute values from the attributes dictionary in 'didStartElement' method:

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
{
    if ([currentElement isEqual:@"Country"]) {
         NSLog(@"Country %@", [attributeDict objectForKey:@"Name"]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the parser method as below:

```
- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)string{
    if(currentKey){
        if(!currentStringValue){
            currentStringValue = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithCapacity:200];
        }
        [currentStringValue appendString:string];
    }
}


    - (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict
    {
        if ([currentElement isEqual:@"Country"]) {
             NSLog(@"Country %@", [attributeDict objectForKey:@"Name"]);
        }
    }
```

Hope it will be helpful to you.

Let me know in case of any difficulty.